# How to disable mouseover event on onclick?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseout

I'm using `mouseover` and `mouseout` event wherein which will change the images on `mouseover` and `mouseout`

And when users click on link, can we disable `mouseout` event, so that that respective function will not be called?

```
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="LikeId" onmouseover="like(1);" onmouseout="like(2);"><span id="greenimg" style="display:none"><img src="images/up_green.gif" border="0" /></span><span id="gimg"><img src="images/up.gif" border="0" /></span></a></td><td width="93%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="DisLikeId" onmouseout="dislike(2);" onmouseover="dislike(1);"><span id="redimg" style="display:none"><img src="images/down_red.gif" border="0" /></span><span id="rimg"><img src="images/down.gif" border="0" /></span></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just set a boolean variable (something like `userClicked = true`) in onclick and check it in your like() function.

In your like function, just surround the code with an if statement.  Such as:

```
function like(parameter) {
    if (!userClicked) {
        // Your original like() code
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, i can check whether user clicked on the link...then how can i disaable mouseover event ?

Comment: Did that answer your question?